# I can't open a lightbox if the anchor is inside a Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, anchor, leaflet

I have a problem. I'm using the "Venobox" plugin, in order to use a modal window when the user wants to see the image on its original size.

In HTML (the common way) this works well, I can open images or html code:

```
<a class="venobox" data-type="iframe" href="acercade.php">
```

But when it comes about using this code on javascript (I'm using it with a Leaflet map), this no longer works.

```
var liga = '<a class="venobox" href="' + enlace + '" target="_blank"><div class="imagen"><img src="' + enlace + '" width="450"></div>';

L.marker([object.get('Latitud'),object.get('Longitud') ], {icon: FaltaDeAguaIcon}).bindPopup(' <p><span class="grande"> ' + object.get('Tipo_Reporte') + ' </span></p><p>Fecha: ' + object.get('Fecha') + ' </p><p>Hora: ' + object.get('Hora') + liga + '<p>Comentarios:<br /> ' + noundefined(object.get('Comentario')) + '</p>').addTo(FaltadeAgua).addTo(todos);
```

What can I do if I want to open the image in the window with the anchor inside the Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Your html is incorrect. 1. You will need to close the <a> Tag. 2.Check if you want an image-venobox if you want an iframe for example you'll have to add an "data-type" attribute. 3. I am not shure if the target attribute is doing any good in there. ```var liga = '<a class="venobox" href="' + enlace + '" ><div class="imagen"><img src="' + enlace + '" width="450"></div></a>';``` should work

Comment: No, it didn't work. The same problem.

Comment: Do you have a public demo anywhere? Or could you create one, because the problem can also be caused by one of the other plugins/frameworks you are using.

Comment: agua-ciudad.org/aguas

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine using this:

```
$('#div').append(
//html to append
//then add this:
                    new VenoBox({
                        selector: '.venobox',
                        titleattr: 'title',
                        titlePosition: 'bottom',
                        numeration: true,
                        infinigall: true,
                        share: true,
                        spinner: 'swing'
                    });
)
```